# What is a basis of a vector space over the smallest finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider a linear map $L:\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2}^{3}$ where $\mathbb{F}_{2}=\{0,1\}$ (the finite field with two elements).

$L$ is such that when defined over $\mathbb{R}$,i.e. $L:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$, it transforms the natural basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ like $L(1,0)=(1,1,3),L(0,1)=(-1,1,1)$.

How does $L$ transform the natural basis of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2}$?

In order to answer this, I need to know what the natural basis of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2}$ is. Lets assume it is the same as $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (although it is not clear to me why).

Then how do I find $L(1,0),L(0,1)$? Since $L(1,0)=(1,1,3)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ do I convert the 3 to 1 and say $L(1,0)=(1,1,1)$?

Since $L(0,1)=(-1,1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ do I convert the $-1$ to $1$ and say $L(0,1)=(1,1,1)$?

Comment: What are the images in $\Bbb F_2^3$ ?

Comment: @Lubin Not positive but $(1,1,3)\rightarrow (1,1,1)$? As far as $(-1,1,1)$ I dont know what $-1$ maps to. Perhaps $1$? In which case $(-1,1,1)\rightarrow (1,1,1)$?

Comment: What does  "when defined over $\Bbb R$" mean? Given that $L$ maps $\Bbb F_2^2$ to $\Bbb F_2^3$ it does _not_ map $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I mean when $L:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ then I know how $L$ transforms the basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2},(1,0),(0,1)$. I am trying then to proceed by analogy and say that when $L:\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2}^{3}$ then it will transform similarly the basis but since $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2}$ doesnt have a $-1$ or a $3$ it must change those differently than in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I read your post, so I know you mean "when $L:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$". That makes no sense! Because given that $L:\Bbb F_2^2\to\Bbb F_2^3$ it is simply not true that $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am completely lost in what you are trying to say. The question gives $L:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and asks what is $L:\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{2}^{3}$, i.e. when we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{F}_{2}$. Thats all. I am not a mathematician so I might be missing some subtlety that is obvious (but not to me).

Comment: It's like you said "Let $p=2$, and suppose that when $p=4$...".

Comment: The question as you wrote it does _not_ give $L:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$. If we _do_ assume that $L:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ then asking what is $L:\Bbb F_2^2\to\Bbb F_2^3$ makes no sense - there's no such thhing as just "replacing $\Bbb R$ by $\Bbb F_2$" here.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The question shows how $L$ transforms a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and hence any vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I imagine this is enough to answer how $L$ transforms the basis of $\mathbb{F}^{2}_{2}$ but I dont know how.

Comment: You can imagine what you want.  What you imagine is irrelevant to mathematical truth. **Look:** Say we define $f:\{1,2\}\to\Bbb R$ by $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=17$. Regardless of what you imagine, this is not enough to determine the value of $f(3)$. The question of determining the value of $f(3)$ makes absolutely no sense, because there is simply np such thing as $f(3)$.

Comment: In $\Bbb F_2$, you have $-1=1$. Thus your two elements of $\Bbb F_2^2$ are going to the same element of $\Bbb F_2^3$.

Comment: @Lubin Huh? Here we have $L:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ and you appear to be saying something about $Lx$ for $x\in\Bbb F_2^2$. What's the _definition_ of $Lx$ here?

Comment: So sorry, @DavidC.Ullrich, I thought OP was asking about a lin.tf. over $\Bbb F_2$, about which he was trying to get information by looking at a supposedly similar lin.tf. over $\Bbb R$. I’m sure that we both agree that this was not a good strategy.